# how to call a function within another variable which has backtick in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to call a function within another variable which has back-tick. how do i make this work?

example:

```
location ()
{echo "home/$1/dir"}

count_files ()
{
count=`ls $(location user1) |wc -l` 
}

count_files
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is always a poor choice - you'll over-count any filenames containing newline here.  Since you're using Bash, better methods exist, using arrays.

Comment: Aside from the use of `ls`, I don't see a problem here. That is a correct use of backticks (though `$(...)` is the preferred syntax for command substitution.)

Comment: (The definition of `location` is broken, but that's unrelated to its use in `count_files`.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this :

```
location() {
   echo "home/$1/dir"
}

count_files() {
   count=$(ls $(location user1) | wc -l)
}

count_files
```

Answer (score -1):

You must set the correct execution syntax.

```
$(Command)
```

or with back-ticks

```
`Command`
```

In your example you missing that bevor the `ls ...` command. And you missing the first slash in your home Directory (Otherwise, it would only work from root `/` Directory.)

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

location () {
  echo "/home/$1/dir"
}

count_files () {

  # Get the count;
  count=$(ls $(location "$1") | wc -l);

  # Return the count value;
  echo "$count";
}

# Call function and print the count result. 
# Better you set the user here and not 'hardcoded' in a function.
echo $(count_files "user1")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: You might want to explain why this gives incorrect results when any file contains a newline in its name.